# is piped ls the same as ls -1?

Tags: shell, ls

`ls` returns output in several columns, whereas `ls|cat` returns byte-identical output with `ls -1` for directories I've tried. Still I see `ls -1` piped in answers, like `ls -1|wc -l`. Is there ever a reason to prefer `ls -1`? Why does `...|cat` change the output of `ls`?

Comment: filenames could contain newlines, so you would count those several times... you could instead posixly do:  `n=0; for i in .* *; do ((n++)) ; done ; echo $n` (drop the .* if you don't want to count those ones). or : `ls -1d ./.* ./* | grep '^\./' | wc -l`  (as filenames can not contain '/')

Comment: `ls` output to a terminal commonly includes color codes by default. For output to a non-terminal, color is typically disabled by default. In GNU, that's `--color={always,auto,never}` IIRC. If color is included in one but not another, then the outputs may appear identical on screen, but they aren't byte-identical (color codes form part of the output of ls).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I think you should write that as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That's something interesting I haven't considered. Is there a general way to always pipe as if outputting to terminal without having to remember the terminal options for color and column output, etc.?

Comment: @rubystallion That sounds like a good separate question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`ls` tests whether output is going to a terminal.  If the output isn't going to a terminal, then `-1` is the default.  (This can be overridden by one of the `-C`, `-m`, or `-x` options.)

Thus, when `ls` is used in a pipeline and you haven't overridden it with another option, `ls` will use `-1`.  *You can rely on this because this behavior is required by POSIX*

#### POSIX Specification

POSIX requires `-1` as the default whenever output is not going to a terminal:

[The POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html):

> The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard
>   output; the exceptions are to terminals or when one of the -C, -m, or
>   -x options is specified. If the output is to a terminal, the format is implementation-defined.

Those three options which override the default single-column format are:

> -C
>  Write multi-text-column output with entries sorted down the columns, according to the collating sequence. The number of text
>   columns and the column separator characters are unspecified, but
>   should be adapted to the nature of the output device. This option
>   disables long format output.
>
> -m
>  Stream output format; list pathnames across the page, separated by a <comma> character followed by a <space> character. Use a
>   <newline> character as the list terminator and after the separator
>   sequence when there is not room on a line for the next list entry.
>   This option disables long format output.
>
> -x
>  The same as -C, except that the multi-text-column output is produced with entries sorted across, rather than down, the columns.
>   This option disables long format output.

#### GNU Documentation

From [GNU ls manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html#General-output-formatting):

> ‘-1’
>  ‘--format=single-column’
>  List one file per line. **This is
>   the default for ls when standard output is not a terminal**. See also
>   the -b and -q options to suppress direct output of newline characters
>   within a file name. [Emphasis added]

#### Examples

Let's create three files:

```
$ touch file{1..3}
```

When output goes to a terminal, GNU `ls` chooses to use a multi-column format:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3
```

When output goes to a pipeline, the POSIX spec requires that single-column is the default:

```
$ ls | cat
file1
file2
file3
```

The three exceptions which override the default single-column behavior are `-m` for comma-separated, `-C` for columns sorted down, and `-x` for columns sorted across:

```
$ ls -m | cat
file1, file2, file3
$ ls -C | cat
file1  file2  file3
$ ls -x | cat
file1  file2  file3
```

Comment: "POSIX requires -1 as the default when output goes to a terminal:" ... but the quote indicates that it requires `-1` as the default **except** when output goes to the terminal (or other conditions)

Comment: @muru Thanks for catching that!  Answer updated.

Comment: Well, every cloud has a silver lining. Because your answer was accepted before mine was posted, I got a funky pizza hat!

Comment: @G-Man Very good.  And, a handsome hat it is!

Answer (score 9):

- Why does piping the standard output change the behavior of `ls`? 
  Because it was designed that way. 
  The [POSIX Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) says:

  > The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard output;
  >   the exceptions are to terminals
  >   or when one of the **`-C`**, **`-m`**, or **`-x`** options is specified. 
  >   If the output is to a terminal, the format is implementation-defined.

  which is actually ambiguous about the default behavior
  (when not specified by an option like `-l` or `-1`)
  with output to a terminal, and the [GNU Coreutils documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html) says

  > If standard output is a terminal,
  >   the output is in columns (sorted vertically)
  >   and control characters are output as question marks;
  >   otherwise, the output is listed one per line
  >   and control characters are output as-is.

  So you can see that output to a file will act the same as output to a pipe;
  that is, one entry per line, as if `-1` had been specified.
- Why was it designed that way? 
  It might not be possible to know for sure
  (unless somebody can find some design notes), but I guess:

  - When `ls` is writing to a terminal,
    it expects that a human being is looking at the output. 
    People will prefer to get information in the minimum necessary
    number of lines, so stuff doesn’t scroll of the screen.
  - When `ls` is writing to a pipe,
    it expects that another program is reading the output. 
    It’s much easier for a program to read data that’s one value per line
    than to have to try to parse columns (since filenames can contain spaces).
- Is there ever a reason to prefer `ls -1`
  when you’re writing to a file or a pipe? 
  No.

Answer (score -4):

When piping ls, ls cannot determine how much columns the console actually has (independant of the right-side command). So ls just does that on its own choice, or, in other words, this behaviour is **unstable** and may change in future versions.

In contrast, `ls -1` was created for the purpose of counting or scripting in general, so its behaviour is stable.

Comment: As the other answers say this behaviour is required by POSIX, so calling it unstable is wrong.