# combine ls -alt with readlink

Tags: ls, sort, readlink

I have a directory containing a lot of symbolic links and some huge subdirectories.   I want to get a detailed listing, sorted by time, of just the files in the parent directory, but with targets replacing links if the files are symbolic links.

The command `readlink -f * | sort | uniq` deals with the symbolic links.  So you would think that

```
ls -alt `readlink -f * | sort | uniq`
```

would simply sort by time the output of the `readlink` command.    But instead it returns the contents, not just of the parent directory, but also all of the subdirectories as well.     How do I get the desired output, i.e., a listing, sorted by time, of *only* the files in the parent directory, with the targets replacing the links?        Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Doesn't the `-L` flag do what you want?  That'll deref symlinks.

Comment: if anything `readlink` returns is a directory, then your `ls` command will list the content of that directory.  If you want to list the directory itself, you'll want to include the `-d` option to `ls`.

Comment: Thanks to both, -L flag does indeed work, To get rid of duplicates wrote a script using readlink as above, then culled the directories out of the list that was returned, and applied `ls -alt` to the culled list.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` and GNU `ls`:

```
files=(*(NDoN:P))
(($#files)) && ls -ltd -- ${(u)files}
```

Or with an anonymous function for brevity:

```
(){ (($#)) && ls -ltd -- ${(u)@}; } *(NDoN:P)
```

where `N` enables `nullglob`, `D` `dotglob` to include hidden files, `oN` skips the sorting as `ls` will sort by mtime and `:P` does the equivalent of GNU `readlink -f`. The `(u)` parameter expansion flag removes duplicates in the array.

Or if there are so many files in the current directory that the above fails with a *too many arguments* errors, you can get `zsh` to do the sorting and pass the list to `ls -U` (to disable its own sorting, requires GNU `ls` or compatible) via `zargs` which like `xargs` would split the list into smaller chunks if needed.

```
autoload zargs
files=(*(ND-om:P))
zargs -r --eof= -- ${(u)files} '' ls -lUd --
```

Where `-om` sorts by modification time after symlink resolution.

(beware `zsh`'s `:P` currently chokes on symlinks that have infinite loops in their resolution).

With `bash` and GNU tools, you could do something approaching with:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
files=(*)
((${#files[@]})) &&
  printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | # prints as NUL-delimited records
  xargs -r0 readlink -zf -- |   # get absolute canonical path
  LC_ALL=C sort -zu |           # removes duplicates
  xargs -r0 stat --printf '%.9Y/%n\0' -- | # get mtime with max precision
  sort -rnz |                   # sort numerically in reverse
  cut -zd/ -f2- |               # remove timestamp added earlier
  xargs -r0 ls -lUd --          # pass to as many ls invocations as needed
```

With small enough lists of files, it can be simplified to:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
files=(*)
((${#files[@]})) &&
  readlink -zf -- "${files[@]}" | # get absolute canonical path
  LC_ALL=C sort -zu |             # removes duplicates
  xargs -r0 ls -ltd --            # pass to ls
```

See how we're always passing the list of files between tools as NUL-delimited records. NUL is the only character (and byte value) that cannot occur in a file path, so the only safe method.

In `readlink -f * | sort`, you're passing the list of files from `readlink` to `sort` as newline-delimited records, so would break with filenames that contain newlines. Since you forgot the `--` before `*`, it would also break on filenames starting with `-`.

It's a lot worse in `` ls -alt `cmd` ``, where this time the output of `cmd` is split on space, tab and newline (assuming the default value of `$IFS`) and filename generation is performed on the resulting words, so it would choke on even more characters. Without `-d`, `ls` would also list the *contents* of the directories it is passed as arguments instead of just the directories themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @Stephane_Chazelas.    I should use `zsh` but don't, so I can't use your suggestion, but I'm sure somebody will

Comment: @LeoSimon If you read the answer til the end, you'll notice I also gave a solution for the bash shell

Comment: Ugh, I"m sorry that was really dumb of me.    That's indeed a much more comprehensive solution to the problem than I'd implemented

Comment: 3 years later, is this still the best apporach?

Answer (score -1):

Consider this approach:

```bash
ls | xargs realpath
ls $PWD | xargs realpath
```

See here why it works without `-1`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410557/537347