# Why doesn't ls -d -R $PWD/* | grep searchforthistext work, but combinations of its components do?

Tags: command-line, grep, ls, recursive

I tried going to `/` and using `ls -d -R $PWD/* | grep searchforthistext` to find any directories or files in my computer with `searchforthistext`, and give me their absolute path (since simply using `ls -R | grep searchforthistext` would only list the names of directories and files, but wouldn't show me where they were). For some reason it did nothing at all; it didn't spit out an error message at me, it just couldn't find anything and went onto the next line awaiting my input.

As a test (in another directory so that I could limit the amount of files would show up to a reasonable number for the test) I ran `ls -d -R $PWD/*` without grepping; this work successfully. Then I ran `ls -d $PWD/* | grep searchforthistext` and was again successful. I did another test though and ran `ls -R | grep searchforthistext`, and again, success.

As a final test I tried `ls -d -R $PWD/* | grep searchforthistext` and noticed that it was finding files with `searchforthistext` in the name and showing their absolute paths, but it was not working recursively (so effectively it was running doing the same thing as `ls -d $PWD/* | grep searchforthistext`).

So to summarize, when using `ls` I can use any two of `-d $PWD/*`, `-R` and `| grep searchforthistext` successfully (so it doesn't seem to be an issue with two of them not working together), but when I try them all together, the recursion fails. I have no idea why this is.

Comment: Use `find` instead of `ls`.

Comment: Also, your description lacks your criteria for success and failure. When something doesn't work as expected, you need to clearly state your expectations and the actual result.

Comment: See also: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/165517)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is piped ls the same as ls -1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410550/is-piped-ls-the-same-as-ls-1)

Comment: Use `find / -name 'searchforthistext'` instead